# Change the name of a cookie with the chrome console/extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My goal is to change a cookies name lets say the name is:

```
cookienameone
```

i want to change the name name of this cookie to

```
cookienamemodified
```

without changing the value i need to do this via the chrome console or via an extension but i couldnt find anything about it.

I hope someone can hel me

Comment: anyone looking for a chrome extension for this can use "Localstorage/Sessionstorage & Cookie Manager". link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstoragesessionstorag/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo/related?hl=en&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome extension "[StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstoragesessionstorag/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo/related?hl=en&authuser=0)" to update cookie names or values.

This extension provides user-friendly UI to manage localstorage, sessionstorage and cookies.

Features:

☄️Manage different storage types - Cookies, Local storage and Session storage

☄️Add new storage items via

```
  ✦ Import JSON

  ✦ Add button
```

☄️Edit selected storage items via

```
  ✦ Edit using UI controls like textboxes, checkbox etc.

  ✦ Edit using custom Editor in JSON format
```

☄️Delete selected storage items

☄️Search storage item

☄️Sort storage items via table columns click.

☄️Import storage data in JSON.

☄️Protect cookies (non-editable)

☄️Block cookies by domain, name and value as needed

☄️Right-click and select StorageAce via Context menu

☄️Export storage items via different formats:

```
  ✦ Local/session storage - JSON

  ✦ Cookies - 

           ⋆ JSON

           ⋆ Netscape HTTP Cookie File

           ⋆ Semicolon separated name=value pairs

           ⋆ Perl::LWP
```

☄️Incognito mode Supported

☄️Beautified JSON View for storage items

☄️Choose path for download.

☄️Ability to Remember last download path.

☄️Extra feature to allow copying JWT using "Copy JWT" button.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the inspector > Application.

[chrome inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkj5d.png)

Comment: thats what i dont want to use i need to change it via the console or an extension